# jQuery slideToggle menus based on mouseenter/leave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've mostly got a little menu system working, but having a couple quirks I can't figure out. There don't seem to be any questions I can find with this same issue.

The functional example is at http://louisnk.com/photography - the only menu that has pretty much all the code in place is 'USA'.

on click, the menu shows, and I want it to:

- A) delay, then slide back up if the mouseenter event never fires

  B) not slide back up if the mouseenter event does fire

  C) delay, then slide back up when the mouseleaves

I have it pretty well down, except I believe I have some event delegation issues...

The first time I click, it all works great. The second time I click on any menu, it seems like 'poked' (the variable which gets set as true/false depending on the switch case) is being set to false, and so automatically causing the 'noPoke' function to close the menu regardless of the mouseenter event. Subsequent clicks obviously cause stranger behavior.

I have the following code all wrapped in a document ready function:

```
var menuSwitch = function(menu) {
    $(menu).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

        switch(e.type) {

            case 'mouseenter':
                poked = true;
                console.log('probed');
                return false;
                break;

            case 'mouseleave':

                $(this).delay(1500).slideUp(500,function() {
                    $(menu + 'li').hide();
                    console.log('switched');
                });                 
                poked = false;
                break;

            default:
                poked = false;
                console.log('defaulting');
                break;
        }
    });
}

var noPoke = function(menu) {
    if (poked == false) {
        $(menu).delay(2000).slideUp(500,function() {
            $(menu + 'ul').hide();
            console.log('no pokes given');
        });
        poked = true;
    }
}

var poked = false;

$('.usa').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    poked = false;      

    $('.usaMenu').slideToggle(500);

    menuSwitch('.usaMenu');

    console.log(poked);

 $('.usaMenu li').on('mouseenter', function() {
        if ($(this).children() != false) {
            $(this).children().fadeTo(200,1);
        }
        else {
            $('.usaMenu li>ul').fadeTo(200,0).hide();
        }
    });

    noPoke('.usaMenu');

});
```

Comment: this is wong `$(menu).on('hover mouseenter mouseleave'` should be: `$(menu).on('mouseenter mouseleave'` or `$(menu).hover(function(){...});`. Hover is a shorthand for onmouseenter/onmouseleave. BTW, i don't see any delegated event in your code

Comment: Thanks, I changed that (I had it the way you said before, and wasn't working) to remove the hover part...sadly didn't fix it.

Comment: Is adding/making available certain functions based on a click function (or any function), not event delegation?

Comment: Basically delegation is bound event to static parent container: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Got it. I will definitely use that page as a reference in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after spending another 6 hours researching and trying different things, I ended up with the following, which solved the problems I was having.

Hopefully this is useful to people trying to do this in the future.

```
var menuSwitch = function(menu) {

    if ($(menu).is(':hover') === false) {
        var hideMe = setTimeout(function() {
            $(menu).slideToggle(500);
        },4000);
    }

    $(menu).on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {

        switch(e.type) {

            case 'mouseenter':

                console.log('probed');
                clearTimeout(hideMe);
                $(this).stop();
                $(this).slideDown(200);
                break;

            case 'mouseleave':

                $(this).delay(2000).slideUp(500,function() {
                    $('li>ul',menu).hide();
                    console.log('switched');
                });                 
                break;
        }
    });
}


var babies = function(menu) {
    $('li',menu).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave click');

    $('li',menu).each(function() {
        if ($('li',menu).children() != false) {

            $(this).on('click',function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).children('ul').slideToggle(300);                    
            });
        }
    });

}


var menuCtrl = function(menu) {
    $(menu).slideToggle(500);

    $(menu).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');

    menuSwitch(menu);

    babies(menu);
}


$('.usa').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    menuCtrl('.usaMenu');

});
```

Ultimately it turned out that because the initial click handler was running the functions every time it fired, it was creating duplicates of the mouseenter/leave event handlers, and therefore causing all sorts of problems. I was also trying to make the menu close if the mouse never entered, in the wrong way.

To solve the most obnoxious issue (duplicate event handlers), I simply used the unbind() api, passing it the events to unbind at the start of the function, so that when they were re-bound, there was only one instance. This may not be the most efficient way, but it works.

To solve the timing/hiding if no mouseenter issue, I used a setTimeout function, which was then cleared if mouseenter-ed.